# Marker not showing up in the center of circle

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

This is my below code which is drawing a Circle within Circle and taking my current location as the center of the circle. And I am showing a Star Sign Marker on my current location.

**Problem Statement:-**

Below code is working fine, but the only problem I am having is, the `Star Sign Marker`, it is not coming in the center of circle. I need my `Star Sign Marker` `(android.R.drawable.star_on)` always in the center of the circle exactly.

`imageNames[0]` is the Center of the Circle (Star Sign Marker) in the below code.

Any suggestions will be of great help to me.

```
    @Override
    public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow, long when) {
        super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);

        Point screenPts = new Point();
        mapView.getProjection().toPixels(pointToDraw, screenPts);
        //--------------draw circle----------------------
        Point pt = mapView.getProjection().toPixels(pointToDraw,screenPts);
        Paint circlePaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        circlePaint.setColor(0x30000000);
        circlePaint.setStyle(Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);

        int totalCircle=4;
        int radius=40;
        int centerimagesize=13;

        for (int i = 1; i <= totalCircle; i ++) { 
            canvas.drawCircle(screenPts.x,screenPts.y, i*radius, circlePaint); 
            canvas.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),imageNames[i]), ((screenPts.x)+(i*radius)),(screenPts.y), null);
        } 

        canvas.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),imageNames[0]), (screenPts.x-(centerimagesize/2)),(screenPts.y-(centerimagesize/2)), null);

        super.draw(canvas,mapView,shadow);

        return true;
    }
```

Below is the screenshot which I am getting currently in my emulator. I need star sign always to be in the center of circle. I am running android 4.1

[image]

Comment: `centerimgagesize` divided by 2 will return 6 (not 6.5), because is integer division. Did you account for that?

Comment: So what it should be actually? Little confused now... :-/

Comment: how did you come up with the value 13 as the centerimagesize? you could also try setting centerimagesize to be of type float.

Comment: I was testing it by putting different different values.

Comment: @TechGeeky it's always better to use float values when you want to work with things like co-ordinates on Google Maps and then if the function absolutely requires an integer only then should you cast it to an integer.

Comment: @TechGeeky has your problem been solved?

Comment: @Warpzit, Not Completely Yet. I am still trying on that. Any suggestions?

Comment: @TechGeeky Did you try to change your values to float instead of int?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it seems like you forgot to take your markers size in account. You should probably start to draw somewhere like:

```
screenPts.x - (centerimagesize + starSignWidth)/2
screenPts.y - (centerimagesize + starSignHeight)/2
```

All you actually do is to tell the canvas to start drawing your markers top left corner in the middle of the screen. Which means that the star markers center won't be the same as your screens center.

The API for Canvas.drawBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, float left, float top, Paint paint) says:

> Draw the specified bitmap, with its top/left corner at (x,y)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint%29

Which is exactly what you do. Your markers top left corner is in the middle of the screen.